# How to solve The given key was not present in the dictionary error?

Tags: c#, key

SO.
It has been 3 hours that I am trying to figure out what could be the problem that throws `The given key was not present in the dictionary.` error but unfortunately being through many SO question and blog posts didn't helped too much.

I have a simple Facebook batch parameters dictionary and when I am iterating through the results it throws the error `The given key was not present in the dictionary`.

Here is the code where the exception is raised:

```
foreach (FacebookPermissionModel permissionResult in
    result.SelectMany(x => x.data).Where(y => y.status == "granted"))
{
    RequiredPermissions[permissionResult.permission].granted = true; // the error comes from here.
}
```

Here is the complete  code:

```
protected List<FacebookPermissionRequest> CheckPermissions(Dictionary<string, FacebookPermissionRequest> RequiredPermissions)
{
    var access_token = HttpContext.Items["access_token"].ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token))
    {
        var appsecret_proof = access_token.GenerateAppSecretProof();
        var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);

        IEnumerable<FacebookPermissionRequest> MissingPermissions =
            new List<FacebookPermissionRequest>();  //initialize to an empty list
        if (MissingPermissions != null)
        {
            //create an array of Facebook Batch Parameters based on list of RequiredPermission
            FacebookBatchParameter[] fbBatchParameters =
                new FacebookBatchParameter[RequiredPermissions.Values.Count()];
            int idx = 0;
            foreach (FacebookPermissionRequest required_permssion in
                RequiredPermissions.Values)
            {

                fbBatchParameters[idx] = new FacebookBatchParameter
                {
                    HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Get,
                    Path = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                            "me/permissions/",
                                            required_permssion.permision_scope_value)
                            .GraphAPICall(appsecret_proof)
                };
                required_permssion.granted = false; //initalize all granted indicators to false for each required permission
                idx++;
            }
            dynamic permission_Batchresult = fb.Batch(
                fbBatchParameters
            );

            if (permission_Batchresult != null)
            {
                List<PermissionResults> result = JsonConvert.
                    DeserializeObject<List<PermissionResults>>
                    (permission_Batchresult.ToString());

                foreach (FacebookPermissionModel permissionResult in
                    result.SelectMany(x => x.data).Where(y => y.status == "granted"))
                {
                    RequiredPermissions[permissionResult.permission].granted = true; // the error comes from here.
                }
                MissingPermissions = RequiredPermissions.Values.
                    Where(p => p.granted == false);
            }
        }
        return MissingPermissions.ToList();
    }
    else
        throw new HttpException(404, "Missing Access Token");
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter look at the code I've pointed out where the code throws the error. Yes I did debug it and both values were shown

Comment: Since you'rve read other questions on stackoverflow i guess you know already how to avoid this excetion with `ContainsKey` etc. But the question is: why do you expect that every `permission` is present as key in the dictionary?

Comment: Just because to find the missing permissions, permission which are not granted

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the dictionary contains the required value before attempting to modify it.

```
foreach (FacebookPermissionModel permissionResult in
                        result.SelectMany(x => x.data).Where(y => y.status == "granted"))
{
    if (RequiredPermissions.ContainsKey(permissionResult.permission))
    {
        RequiredPermissions[permissionResult.permission].granted = true;
    {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
some permissions not there in RequiredPermissions

            if (RequiredPermissions.ContainsKey(permissionResult.permission))
                RequiredPermissions[permissionResult.permission].granted = true; // the error comes from here.
            else
                Debug.WriteLint("RequiredPermissions obj does not contain this key " + permissionResult.permission);
```